# priority of operators in C language

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Hi I'm learning C language and I have learned that `()` have more priority than  `&&` in C,
but when I execute the following program, `a` gard it's value although that it has been placed between `()` can I get any explanation please ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    a=2,b=4;
    printf("%d\n",0&&(a=b));
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&&` is *short-circuiting*.

Comment: `a` does not gets assigned the value of `b` because the whole expression can only be `false`, from `0 && ... ` and the second part `(a=b)` is not evaluated.

Comment: And also it should be `(a==b)` instead of  `(a=b)`.

Comment: @EugeneSh is short-circuiting only for `&&` operator or there is some other cases ?

Comment: @black OP is surprised that assignment did not happen. That change would eliminate the question, not answer it.

Comment: @LEARNER Also for `||` and `?:`. Short circuiting is a common convention across most languages where operators are so named.

Comment: @black No I wanted to test the priority between `&&` and `()`, if the value of `a` changed that means that `()` are prioritized in C, but the second expression `(a=b)` doesn't even get executed!

Comment: @Potatoswatter thank you so much, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators both *short-circuit* - that is, if the value of the expression can be determined from the left operand, then the right operand will not be evaluated at all.

Given the expression `a && b`, if `a` evaluates to 0 (false), then the value of the entire expression will be false *regardless* of the value of `b`, so `b` isn't evaluated.

Given the expression `a || b`, if `a` evaluates to non-zero (true), then the value of the entire expression is true (1) *regardless* of the value of `b`, so `b` is not evaluated.

In your example, `0 && (a=b)`, the left operand is `0`, so the expression will evaluate to `0` (false) regardless of what happens with `(a=b)`, so `(a=b)` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

It's because when the left-most statement in logical `&&` is false, then right-most statement will not be calculated\executed.